# Reading a CSV file detecting last field in file

Tags: c++, file, parsing, stringstream

I'm trying to read a CSV file and I have three fields that I'm supposed to read in and the very last field is an integer and I am crashing on the last line of the file with stoi function since there is no newline character and I am not sure how to detect when I am on the last line. The first two getline statements are reading the first two fields and my third getline is reading and expecting an integer and my delimiter for that one only is '\n' but this will not work for the very last line of input and I was wondering was there any workaround for this?

My field types that I am expecting are [ int, string, int ] and I have to include spaces with the middle field so I don't think using stringstream for that will be effective

```
while (! movieReader.eof() ) { // while we haven't readched end of file
    stringstream ss;
    getline(movieReader, buffer, ','); // get movie id and convert it to integer
    ss << buffer; // converting id from string to integer
    ss >> movieid;
    getline(movieReader, movieName, ','); // get movie name
    getline(movieReader, buffer, '\n');
    pubYear = stoi(buffer); // buffer will be an integer, the publish year
    auto it = analyze.getMovies().emplace(movieid, Movie(movieid, movieName, pubYear ) );
    countMovies++;
}
```

Comment: The input consists of lines ending with a newline character. This is the ideal task for `std::getline`: to read input, one line at a time. With its third parameter left at the default `'\n'`. Now you're happily reading your input, one line at a time, with no complication. According to your shown code, you are familiar with `std::istringstream` and you know how it works. Did you know that it can be constructed with a single `std::string` parameter? So now, you simply take each individual line, put it into a `std::istringstream`, and trivially extract each field.  The End.

Comment: Yes but for me I am doing titles that have spaces in them so when I try to do ss >> movieName, it's not going to pick up the spaces in the name. Not sure how to work around that.

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way around. Don't Do: check for error (eof()), read, process data. DO: read, check for error, process data. Also would you please update your question with sample data?

Comment: Nevermind it's still not working I gotta work on this. It was working and now it's not. Thank you Swordfish. What do you mean by that? You mean ( while getline(movieReader, buffer, ',' ) && !movieReader.eof() all in the while condition?

Comment: Your "work around that" by doing exactly what you already did here, by using `std::getline` with the optional delimiter set to `','`. After all, there is no law that says that if you use `std::getline()` to read one line at a time, this legally prohibits you from putting each such read line into another stream, and then using `std::getline` on that second stream, again, to extract each ,-delimited field.

Comment: [Some light reading](https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/) on why using eof in a loop conditional is bad.

Comment: . o O ( I'm not a big fan of reading from one stream just to stuff it into another ...)

Answer (score 0):

For reading and writing objects one would idomatically overload the stream extraction and stream insertion operators:

#### Sample csv:

```
1, The Godfather, 1972
2, The Shawshank Redemption, 1994
3, Schindler's List, 1993
4, Raging Bull, 1980
5, Citizen Kane, 1941
```

#### Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

void skip_to(std::istream &is, char delim) // helper function to skip the rest of a line
{

    char ch;
    while ((ch = is.get()) && is && ch != delim);
}

std::istream& eat_whitespace(std::istream &is) // stream manipulator that eats up whitespace
{
    char ch;
    while ((ch = is.peek()) && is && std::isspace(static_cast<int>(ch)))
        is.get();
    return is;
}

class Movie
{
    int movieid;
    std::string movieName;
    int pubYear;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Movie &movie)
    {
        Movie temp;  // use a temporary to not mess up movie with a half-
        char ch;     // extracted dataset if we fail to extract some field.

        if (!(is >> temp.movieid))  // try to extract the movieid
            return is;

        if (!(is >> std::skipws >> ch) || ch != ',') { // read the next non white char
            is.setf(std::ios::failbit);                // and check its a comma
            return is;
        }

        is >> eat_whitespace; // skip all whitespace before the movieName
        if (!std::getline(is, temp.movieName, ',')) {  // read the movieName up to the
            return is;                                 // next comma
        }

        if (!(is >> temp.pubYear))                     // extract the pubYear
            return is;

        skip_to(is, '\n');  // skip the rest of the line (or till eof())
        is.clear();

        movie = temp;  // all went well, assign the temporary
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Movie const &movie)
    {
        os << "Nr. " << movie.movieid << ": \"" << movie.movieName << "\" (" << movie.pubYear << ')';
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    char const * movies_file_name{ "foo.txt" };
    std::ifstream is{ movies_file_name };

    if (!is.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open \"" << movies_file_name << "\"!\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::vector<Movie> movies{ std::istream_iterator<Movie>{is},
                               std::istream_iterator<Movie>{} };

    for (auto const & m : movies)
        std::cout << m << '\n';
}
```

#### Output:

```
Nr. 1: "The Godfather" (1972)
Nr. 2: "The Shawshank Redemption" (1994)
Nr. 3: "Schindler's List" (1993)
Nr. 4: "Raging Bull" (1980)
Nr. 5: "Citizen Kane" (1941)
```